# How to resolve "ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list" caused MySQL 5.7 with SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I installed the new Ubuntu and my code has got a problem with MySQL.

```
( ! ) Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3065 
Expression #2 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'clicshopping_test_ui.p.products_date_added' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT 
in /home/www//boutique/includes/OM/DbStatement.php on line 97s
```

It seems MySQL 5.7 does'nt allow a request like:

```
select .... distinct with  order by rand(), p.products_date_added DESC
```

If I use this it works:

```
select distinct .... with  order by rand(),
```

How to resolve this situation ?

My SQL request in PHP

```
 $Qproduct = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select distinct p.products_id,
            p.products_price
            from :table_products p left join :table_specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id
            where products_status = :products_status
            and products_view = :products_view
            and p.products_archive = :products_archive
            order by rand(),
            p.products_date_added DESC
            limit :products_limit');
                  $Qproduct->bindInt(':products_status', 1);
                  $Qproduct->bindInt(':products_view', 1);
                  $Qproduct->bindInt(':products_archive', 0);
                  $Qproduct->bindInt(':products_limit', 
                  (int)MODULE_FRONT_PAGE_NEW_PRODUCTS_MAX_DISPLAY);
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, could show me an example  because it's two different function  select distinct .... and select .....from ... group by

Comment: `group by` does not work here as suggested by user557846. If you use `group by` you can't order by the other field.

Answer (score 99):

If you have control of the server and you are running legacy code you can't easily change, you can [adjust the SQL mode of the server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) and remove "only_full_group_by" either for the duration of boot, by running the query

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

or by adding `sql_mode=''` to your my.cnf file.

Obviously its better to change your code if you have the possibility, but if not, this will disable that warning.

Comment: For reference, if you go the route of adding `sql_mode=''` to your my.cnf file, be sure to add this line under a new line with the `[mysqld]` heading. For example: `[mysqld]` (new line) `sql_mode = ''`. Otherwise, you'll get an error when attempting to restart `mysql`, like: `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

Comment: Thank you! I had 2 computers and in one of them the code worked and in the other one not, and thanks to you I solved it

Comment: The `SET GLOBAL` query did not help.

Comment: @ValerianPereira The following worked for me: SET @@sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

Comment: As us developers are often working with legacy systems, I wanted to know if there were performance issues associated with turning 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' off. 

I found that the offending queries did not run any faster when I fixed the syntax to be compatible compared to running them with  'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' off. I could not see any obvious performance benefit then to fixing the queries or issues with disabling the mode.

Comment: >>> 
Obviously its better to change your code if you have the possibility
>>>

Is there any performance penalty if I remove "only_full_group_by"

Comment: `Obviously its better to change your code if you have the possibility,` why? And how would you suggest to change it?

Comment: @Adam According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668890/2336725, the fix is that anything in ORDER BY also needs to be in SELECT.

Answer (score 17):

In order to fix the issue open the following file:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

and add the following line under [mysqld] block

```
sql-mode=""
```

Comment: `sql-mode` or `sql_mode`? or doesn't matter?

Comment: it should be sql-mode

Answer (score 13):

1. You can run as said :

```sql
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

But if you restart your serveur, you may have to re run it.

---

2. You can update the mysql server configuration:

- on Windows, the **${MY_SQL_HOME}/my.cnf** (or **my.ini**)
- on Linux, one of the following: **etc/my.cnf**, **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**, **/usr/etc/my.cnf** or **~/.my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]

# RESOLVE order-by-clause-is-not-in-select-list by removing ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY from the sql-mode list
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have phpMyAdmin:

1-go to the Variables tabs

2-search label "sql mode"

3-edit the content and delete the mode : "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY"

4-save

NB: don't forget to verify the comma separator

Comment: This works but if super privilege is not turned on it would return error.

Answer (score 3):

With MAMP PRO

You cannot edit your my.cnf file directly. 
You must use the MAMP PRO interface to edit your my.cnf file. 
In the menu go to File > Edit Template > MySQL > my.cnf.
Then add `sql_mode=''` under the `[mysqld]` key

Comment: With MAMP, create the file my.cnf in your /Applications/MAMP/conf folder, add these lines and restart the server:

`[mysqld]`
`sql_mode=''`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me that @pvgoran suggested

```
SET @@sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

You can run this when you want.

Answer (score 2):

To get `->distinct('some_column')` to work for me, I needed to disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option in mysql modes.

Rather than edit the mysql config file on the filesystem, I followed the instructions at [Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error) and added this to `config/database.php`:

```
        'strict' => true,
        'modes' => [
            // 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // disabled to allow grouping by one column
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ],
```

In my project, the `modes` property was non-existent, so I simply pasted that bad boy in there.

> **NOTE**: Make sure you understand that wiping the modes entirely is undesirable, and basically not strict mode, so you will lose debugging warning/error messages about stuff like varchar length exceeded. The trick is to avoid `sql_mode=""`. Notice how above I am using 6 modes and explicitly omitting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT p.products_id,  p.products_price  
      FROM :table_products p
 LEFT JOIN :table_specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id 
     WHERE
           products_status = :products_status AND
           products_view = :products_view AND
           p.products_archive = :products_archive
  ORDER BY rand(),  p.products_date_added DESC
  GROUP BY p.products_id,p.products_price 
     LIMIT :products_limit
```