# Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, qsqlquery

I want to use WhereIn and Groupby in the same query to fetch Result.

I've tried this:

```
$loadids=explode("#@*",$reciptdet->loading_id);
$loadingdatas=DB::table('loading')->groupBy('vehicle_no')->whereIn('id',$loadids)->get();
```

But I got this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sbrtpt.loading.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from loading where id in (14, 15, 16) group by vehicle_no)

Comment: Switch your groupBy and whereIn statements around

Comment: Its Not working @aynber

Comment: Can you print your full error message?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'sbrtpt.loading.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `loading` where `id` in (14, 15, 16) group by `vehicle_no`)   @aynber

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-isnt-in-group-by

Answer (score 379, accepted):

### Short answer

In `config\database.php` --> `"mysql"` array

Set `'strict' => false` to disable all.

### ....   or

You can leave `'strict' => true` and add modes to `"mysql"` option in

```
'mysql' => [
       ...
       ....
       'strict' => true,
       'modes' => [
            //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Disable this to allow grouping by one column
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ],
 ]
```

---

### Detailed answer

You may not need to disable all **strict** options ...
Kindly have a look on this [answer](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997#issuecomment-242129087) about this issue.

Comment: How can we set this strict mode to false on oracle connection in laravel?
Please help me

Comment: @VikasChauhan, Sorry I didn't use Oracle before

Comment: This worked!!! 
For anybody who is still getting the same error after changing that setting, try clearing the config cache by running `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: My concern about this kind of hard-coded workaround is that I feel some kind of technical debt that will not make me sleep well at night, because the kind of questions that will be floating in my head will be like: what happens when Laravel and/or MySQL spec changes wrt the `modes` (e.g. addition/removal of some of the modes specified in that array, or worse still, the name of one of the modes specified in that array changes). So, I just leave `strict=true` and won't touch any `mode` thing. I'll rather update my code to work with such strict setting. `ThisPractice === SleepWellEveryNight` :)

Comment: @Husam may I know what is the pros and cons disabling strict? Thanks for the answer

Comment: A much better solution is write better SQL

Comment: I wasted hours messing with different things, attempting to set the permission globally and had no idea that config option was available!

Answer (score 128):

This is probably a [SQL_MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) problem. In your `config/database.php`, in the connection, change

```
strict => false
```

As in

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: In this Method can make any security issue @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro

Comment: I believe it's safe or you would not have an option on Laravel to disable it.

Comment: Don't forget to execute this command after applying the change: php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 48):

No need to change any where in your System jut use code like in laravel

```
\DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");//this is the trick use it just before your query

$data=Task::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 0)->groupBy('task_code')->get(['id','task_code', 'title']);
```

Comment: Thanks this works like charm 
\DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");

Comment: Thank you, been searching and trying all other solution and not work on me. Your solution is simple and works. 

Thank you so much

Comment: It's My pleasure Mr. @KyusufMuhammad and Mr. Vinit Kadkol .

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm

Comment: Thank you @SkBindas, it worked for me too. Also I think this is the best solution since it does not change global settings.

Comment: Thank you @SkBindas this seems to be a much safer way if you are running only one query other than setting it for the whole application

Answer (score 16):

## Without modifiying `config\database.php` file

**Set `'strict' => false`** in the `config\database.php` could be a **security issue**. So, a simple Laravel solution could be **first call `get()` and then `groupBy('vehicle_no)`**:

```
$loadids = explode("#@*", $reciptdet->loading_id);
$loadingdatas = DB::table('loading')->whereIn('id', $loadids)->get();
$grouped = $loadingdatas->groupBy('vehicle_no');
```

Comment: I couldn't get proper result when 'strict' => false. then this solution works well if you try group data when query. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You do not want to group by on the web server, you want that group by to be done in SQL. Try your group by approach with a table of 147mil records...

Comment: Don't do that if you have a big data. Groupping the data outside SQL will kill the performance.

Answer (score 14):

update `config/database.php`

set:

```
'mysql' => [
     'strict' => false,
],
```

instead of:

```
'mysql' => [
     'strict' => true,
],
```

and don't forget to clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: beside being replied in 2016 if i can vote you a thousand time i will . banging with it about 24 hours without any clue its being cached. Love you man <3

Answer (score 12):

You can leave `'strict' => true` and add modes to "mysql" option in.

```
'mysql' => [
   ...
   ....
   'strict' => true,
   'modes' => [
        //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Disable this to allow grouping by one column
        'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        // 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER', // This has been deprecated and will throw an error in mysql v8

        'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
    ],
 ]
```

Comment: I think this is much better than setting to false

Comment: What does "strict" even do? Is there any documentation for that configuration option?

Answer (score 8):

I was having this problem also but after changing  `'strict' => true`, to  `'strict' => false`, the error disappeared.

You can find this setting in:

**config\database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => false,
    ...
]
```

Comment: How can we do that for oracle connectiion in laravel

Answer (score 8):

Whenever using groupBy in eloquent, always include the column name used in the groupBy function in the select() function.

```
$loadids=explode("#@*",$reciptdet->loading_id);
$loadingdatas=DB::table('loading')->select('vehicle_no')->groupBy('vehicle_no')->whereIn('id',$loadids)->get();//add select('vehicle_no')
```

Also it is a bad practice to disable strict mode in the config file. Doing so may cause corrupt data to enter the database such as invalid dates without any warnings.Don't do that unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Addition of ->select('column') worked for me. 
Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 6):

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055  in GROUP BY
```

If you get the above error, add the following into your `database.php` file in the `config` folder:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'strict' => true,
    'modes' => [
        'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
        'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 6):

Later, after googling for a while, I learnt that the problem was caused by the `sql_mode` setting, and modified the configuration of **config/database.php** as `strict => false`.

Refer to: https://stdworkflow.com/147/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error

Comment: Indeed, setting like this solved my problem: 
\DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");

Answer (score 3):

This restriction makes sense as when you use `GROUP BY` in MySQL, it returns one row for each value in the columns used in `GROUP BY`. So, the values of other columns in the selected rows do not make sense to use anywhere. So, it's always recommended to use the best practice and I would recommend not to disable MySQL Strict Mode.

Often developers may need rows of a query grouped by the value of a column. Here they don't need only one row per the unique values of the columns. But they need multiple rows grouped by the unique values of a particular column. For some reason, they use `groupBy` Query Builder method of Laravel which generates a MySQL `GROUP BY` query and the developers encounter the above error.

The solution to their problem is to use `groupBy` Collection method instead. For example,

```
$loadingData = DB::table('loading')
    ->whereIn('id', $loadIds)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('vehicle_no');
```

This will give them the desired result.

Comment: You do not want to group by on the web server, you want that group by to be done in SQL. Try your group by approach with a table of 147mil records...

Comment: @JohnC In that case, they need to write the queries differently.

Comment: the only thing you are missing from it being a valid SQL group by, is a valid select. That's all the issue is in all of these...

Comment: @JohnC Yes, of course. You can do that. My answer only addresses the error in the question.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, the answer is to simply add the correct select statement, and not group by after you made the query.

Comment: @JohnC What if you need to select more columns than the group by columns?

Comment: That would break the query, as the SQL-92 standard does not allow selecting anything but grouped and aggregated columns in the select clause when using group by. If you are using MySQL, you can use GROUP_CONCAT or ANY_VALUE to work around that limitation.

Answer (score 3):

You might as well use:

**distinct('vehicle_no')**

instead of groupBy('vehicle_no') each case scenario is different, but looking at your query, distinct might be the way to go since you're not aggregating data.

Answer (score 2):

This is on laravel doc 8.x , it works well

```
 $users = DB::table('users')
             ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
             ->where('status', '<>', 1)
             ->groupBy('status')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

add `\Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` to `boot` method

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
         \Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve a similar issue with using group by by first getting the columns i needed to sort then use the group by.

```
$SampleData= DB::table('tableExampleName')->get(['col1','col2'])->groupBy('col3');
```

then you can dd() the values and check if they are the right grouping. You can all assign it and pass it into your view for further testing.

**Note**: This is using **Laravel 8**.

Comment: You do not want to group by on the web server, you want that group by to be done in SQL. Try your group by approach with a table of 147mil records...