# laravel 5 inner join and group by query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

please help me with my format query in laravel 5. I am a beginner in using laravel 5, and i just search to came up with this query, but now i am getting error i dont know where and why? i think my error is only in syntax?

Here is my code:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker2));

$products =  DB::table('shipping_table')
->select('products.product_name', 'products.price', 'Sum(shipping_products.quantity) AS qtysold', 'shipping_table.sold_date')
->join('shipping_products','shipping_table.shipping_id', '=', 'shipping_products.shipping_id')
->join('products','products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id')
->where([['DATE(shipping_table.sold_date)', '=',$date], ['shipping_table.shipping_status', '=' ,1]])
->groupBy('products.product_name')
->paginate(8);
```

any suggestions? i printed the error and it says this :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE(shipping_table.sold_date)' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: You have extra`[` here :- `->where([['DATE(shipping_table.sold_date)', '=',$date, ['shipping_table.shipping_status', '=' ,1]])`

Comment: Wait! Do you really have that column in your table?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi yes i have.. the problem was solved but another error comes SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Sum(shipping_products.quantity)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra starting `[` in this line:-

```
->where([['DATE(shipping_table.sold_date)', '=',$date, ['shipping_table.shipping_status', '=' ,1]])
```

It need to be (use `DB::raw()` to use `mysql functions`):-

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->datepicker2));

$products =  DB::table('shipping_table')
->select('products.product_name', 'products.price', DB::raw("Sum(shipping_products.quantity) as qtysold"), 'shipping_table.sold_date')
->join('shipping_products','shipping_table.shipping_id', '=', 'shipping_products.shipping_id')
->join('products','products.product_id', '=', 'shipping_products.product_id')
->where([[DB::raw("date(shipping_table.sold_date)"),$date], ['shipping_table.shipping_status', '=' ,1]])
->groupBy('products.product_name')
->paginate(8);
```

Note:-

Regarding the error you get (`Syntax error or access violation: 1055`) check this answer and do accordingly:-

[aravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984930/4248328)

Comment: You only are doing 1 query so by definition you're not suffering from the N+1 problem.

Comment: @JcJohn  use my `Or` section answer.  replace your code with this code and check

Comment: @AlivetoDie btw sir, thanks for helping. I have already run this query in navicat but i got stuck in this laravel framework

Comment: in your `config/database.php`  search for `strict=>..` and if it's true then make it `false` and check

Comment: check this and do like this answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984930/4248328