# Summation query using groupBy() function in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

A table where X, Y and Z have some individual amounts.

Sample data:

```
Name | Amount |  Date
—————|————————|—————————
  X  |    100 | 15-11-17
  Y  |     50 | 15-11-17
  X  |     50 | 15-11-17
  Z  |     70 | 15-11-17
  Z  |     30 | 15-11-17
```

Now I want to show a table where X will return one row with the summation of it's two values in the same date.

Expected result:

```
Name | Amount |  Date
—————|————————|—————————
  X  |    150 | 15-11-17
  Y  |     50 | 15-11-17
  Z  |    100 | 15-11-17
```

So what is the laravel query for that? I use groupBy(). But can't get the targeted result.

Here is my laravel query code

```
$data = DB::table('transactions')                
            ->select('transactions.*')
            ->groupBy('transactions.title_id')
            ->whereDate('transactions.created_at', '=', $date)
            ->get();
```

And got this error continuously

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'finance_report.transactions.id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Anybody please help

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried.

Comment: Paul Spiegel - I have updated my question. please check

Comment: I replaced your images with text tables in code blocks. Next time please do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table name is `transactions`, and the columns and data like in your sample table - The SQL query would be

```sql
SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) as Amount, Date
FROM transactions
GROUP BY Name, Date
```

In laravel you would write it as

```php
$data = DB::table('transactions')                
    ->select('Name', DB::raw('SUM(Amount) as Amount'), 'Date')
    ->groupBy('Name', 'Date')
    ->get();
```

You can add your WHERE conditions and what ever you need to the query. But if you need to select more columns from the table, you will also need to add them to the `groupBy()` clause. Something like `transactions.*` will probably not work due to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode. But it also probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It works....
One other question that, can I use any 'date()' function inside 'groupBy()' to convert my date from timestamp to date only ?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to use `DB::raw()` like `->groupBy('Name', DB::raw('DATE(Date)'))`. But then you should do the same in the SELECT clause: `->select('Name', DB::raw('SUM(Amount) as Amount'), DB::raw('DATE(Date) as Date'))`.

Comment: Thanks paul. It works again.
I didn't use `DB::raw('DATE(Date)')` in `select` part. just only inside the `groupBy()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM(Amount) with groupBy(date)

Comment: seravee - according to your query all the amount on same date will sum. But I don't want that. I want all the amount of a same name on a same date will SUM.

Comment: Can you try with groupBy('date', 'name')

Comment: seravee - yes. And i got this error
`"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'finance_report.transactions.id' isn't in GROUP BY`

Comment: @Arafat i think issue not related with the above query, have a look at this link, 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error