# How to do summation query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

A table where x,y and z have some individual amounts like image1.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz1Rw.jpg)

Now I want to show a table where each 'name' will have one row with the summation of it's multiple rows of values in the same date like image 2.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYBOI.jpg)

So what is the laravel query for that?

Comment: What is the difference to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362435/summation-query-using-groupby-function-in-laravel)?

Comment: No differnce Paul. Change the title just. Still not getting the answer. That's why need to resubmit the question again :(

Comment: I wrote an answer to your first question and vote to close this one as duplicate question. Note that if a simple question like this doesn't receive any helpfull answers, than something is wrong about the question. Reposting it without significant changes will probably not help anyone.