# Laravel Error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055

Tags: php, database, laravel

why the query syntax in the Laravel application can't be run but it can be in phpmyadmin syntax, namely:

```
$dataTanggal = DB::select('SELECT CONCAT (YEAR(tanggal_pinjam),"-",LPAD(MONTH(tanggal_pinjam), 2, '0')) as tanggal_pinjam, COUNT(*) As jumlah_data FROM `riwayat_pinjam` GROUP BY YEAR(tanggal_pinjam),MONTH(tanggal_pinjam)');
```

and the error in the laravel is :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
> 'sipirang.riwayat_pinjam.tanggal_pinjam' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL:
> SELECT * from lihatperbulan)

can anyone help? please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error)

Answer (score 0):

seems you have wrong si gle quote aroud 0, avoid ambiguity between column name  tanggal_pinjam and alias  tanggal_pinjam (use a different alias eg: my_ tanggal_pinjam), and use the same code  for group by

```
  $dataTanggal = DB::select('SELECT CONCAT (YEAR(tanggal_pinjam),"-"
        , LPAD(MONTH(tanggal_pinjam), 2, "0")) as my_tanggal_pinjam
        , COUNT(*) As jumlah_data 
        FROM `riwayat_pinjam` 
        GROUP BY YEAR(tanggal_pinjam),MONTH(tanggal_pinjamLPAD(MONTH(tanggal_pinjam), 2, "0")))');
```