# How to Get All Records and Group Them by create_at (Date Only)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table named `shopping_apps,` and that table has different entries on different dates. I want to have all records but group all the records on a date basis (not the time part). Suppose I have 20 entries on `date1`, 12 entries on `date2`. I want to have only two values extracted from the database: `date1` and `date2`. The controller is below, and `Shopping_app` is my model name.

```php
<?php

// Use substr() to retrieve date part 10 chars in length.
$shoppingApp = Shopping_app::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy(substr('created_at', 0, 10))
    ->get();
```

ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'laravelpro4.shopping_apps.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from
>   `shopping_apps` group by `created_at` order by `created_at` desc)

Answer (score 1):

```
$shoppingApp = Shopping_app::where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now->subMonth())
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'))
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

try this maybe it will help you

Comment: ERROR: 
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravelpro4.shopping_apps.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `shopping_apps` where `created_at` >= 2019-01-02 12:20:53 group by Date(created_at) order by `created_at` desc)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error] Look this for it

Answer (score 1):

So with the help of @manish I get the correct answer (what I was trying to get)

Error solved by

Adding false

In `config\database.php` --> **"mysql"** array
Set **'strict' => false** to disable all.

Final code :

```
$shoppingApp = Shopping_app::where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth())
                    ->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'))
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```