# Can you run a sub select query inside a raw query in laravel? If yes where am I going wrong? Here's my query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

```
DB::table('awarded_contracts as ac')
        ->select(
            DB::raw("COUNT(ac.id) AS numOfContracts"),
            DB::raw("SUM(ac.contract_amount) AS sumOfContractAmounts"),
            DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(bid_submissions.id) from bid_submissions where bid_submissions.bid_invitation_id = ac.bid_invitation_id) AS numOfBidSubmissions"),
            DB::raw("(CASE WHEN bi.procurement_method_id ='0' THEN pm.title  ELSE pm2.title END) as method")

        )

        ->join('bid_invitations as bi', function ($q) {
            $q->on('bi.id', '=', 'ac.bid_invitation_id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('procurement_plan_entries as ppe', function ($q) {
        $q->on('ppe.id', '=', 'bi.procurement_plan_entry_id');
        })
        ->join('procurement_methods as pm', function ($q) {
            $q->on('ppe.procurement_method_id', '=', 'pm.id');
        })
        ->leftJoin('procurement_methods as pm2', function ($q) {
            $q->on('pm2.id', '=', 'bi.procurement_method_id');
        })

        ->groupBy('method')
        ->get();
```

I want my subquery to count results in another table but the query is bringing syntax error issue. here's the error i get

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tenderpo_2019.ac.bid_invitation_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select COUNT(ac.id) AS numOfContracts, SUM(ac.contract_amount) AS sumOfContractAmounts, (SELECT COUNT(bid_submissions.id) from bid_submissions where bid_submissions.bid_invitation_id = ac.bid_invitation_id) AS numOfBidSubmissions, (CASE WHEN bi.procurement_method_id ='0' THEN pm.title  ELSE pm2.title END) as method from `awarded_contracts` as `ac` inner join `bid_invitations` as `bi` on `bi`.`id` = `ac`.`bid_invitation_id` left join `procurement_plan_entries` as `ppe` on `ppe`.`id` = `bi`.`procurement_plan_entry_id` inner join `procurement_methods` as `pm` on `ppe`.`procurement_method_id` = `pm`.`id` left join `procurement_methods` as `pm2` on `pm2`.`id` = `bi`.`procurement_method_id` left join `procurement_types` as `pt` on `pt`.`id` = `ppe`.`procurement_type_id` where `ac`.`financial_year` = 2018-2019 group by `method`)
```

Comment: add your error too

Comment: Yes you can use a sub select like one you've added. You need to share the syntax error as well to debug further.

Comment: I have shared the error  i hope it makes things a tag clearer

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error

Comment: @CengkuruMichael does is it work?