# Return duplicate data when i use Join Query in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, distinct

When i try to use inner join query in laravel 5.8, returned duplicate datas..

There are 2 groups and 8 products in the database. When I want to print group names from database, instead of printing 2 group names, it prints the number of products to screen (8 groups names).

I tried Laravel ->distinct() and some different methods but doesn't work.

That's my controller codes:

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
$captions = DB::table('ab_captions')->where('ab_groups.user_id', $user_id)->where('ab_captions.user_id', $user_id)->join('ab_groups', 'ab_captions.group_id', '=', 'ab_groups.id')->distinct()->get();
    if ($captions == !NULL) {
        return view('default.captions', ['captions' => $captions]);
    } else {
        return view('default.captions');
    }
```

And blade codes:

```
@if(!empty($captions)) 
    @foreach($captions as $showcaptions)
        <div class="list-body" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <a href="{{ url('captions/'.$showcaptions->groupname) }}" class="item-title _500">{{ $showcaptions->groupname }}</a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

And output like this:

Groupname-1

Groupname-2

Groupname-2

Groupname-2

Groupname-2

Groupname-2

Groupname-2

Groupname-2

As i said, i have 2 group names (Groupname-1 and Groupname-2)

I know it's a simple problem, but I haven't been able to solve it even though I've researched a lot. Really thank you for your help.

Comment: If you need only groups, you can simply get it from the `ab_groups` table. In this case, you do not need any join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause, to group your result according to `group_id` or `group_name`

```
$captions = DB::table('ab_captions')->where('ab_groups.user_id', $user_id)->where('ab_captions.user_id', $user_id)->join('ab_groups', 'ab_captions.group_id', '=', 'ab_groups.id')->groupBy('ab_captions.group_id')->get();
```

Comment: Sorry, how exactly can I do this?

Comment: Error.. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'autobot.ab_captions.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `ab_captions` inner join `ab_groups` on `ab_captions`.`group_id` = `ab_groups`.`id` where `ab_groups`.`user_id` = 1 and `ab_captions`.`user_id` = 1 group by `ab_groups`.`id`)

Comment: I think this is a different problem, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error) please.