# Why following query giving error in laravel project?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am writing inner join query and calculating count and average rating using formula of `count` and `avg` of mysql. This query is run in mysql but it gives error in laravel.

What changes can I make in code? I need changes in my query.

**The Error:**

```sql
"(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 
    'ecommerce.table_sub_category.sub_category_id' 
    isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select table_rating_review.product_id,COUNT(*) 
    as count_review,avg(rating) as rating, table_sub_category.sub_category_id,
    table_product.brand_id,table_product.product_id, 
    table_product.product_name, table_product.product_image,table_product.product_price 
    from table_sub_category inner join table_product 
    on table_sub_category.sub_category_id=table_product.sub_category_id inner join table_rating_review on table_product.product_id=table_rating_review.product_id where 
    table_sub_category.sub_category_id=1 group by table_rating_review.product_id)"
```

**My query:**

```php
$get_product_details=
    DB::select('select table_rating_review.product_id,COUNT(*) as count_review,avg(rating) 
    as rating,table_sub_category.sub_category_id,table_product.brand_id,table_product.product_id,table_product.product_name,table_product.product_image,table_product.product_price from table_sub_category inner join table_product on table_sub_category.sub_category_id=table_product.sub_category_id inner join table_rating_review on table_product.product_id=table_rating_review.product_id where table_sub_category.sub_category_id=? group by table_rating_review.product_id',[$sub_category_id]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error)

Comment: @aceraven777 Thank u . u save my time