# Laravel Access Violation Error QueryException 42000

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Database name :- **'hdwallpapers'**

Table :- **'images'**

[image]

Table :- **'categories'**

[image]

Whenrever I run the following query it generates output shown in the image.

```
select categories.cid, categories.category_name, COUNT(images.category) as "Count" from categories LEFT JOIN images on categories.cid=images.category GROUP BY categories.category_name ORDER BY categories.category_name
```

Output

[image]

I've created Laravel App called **"HDWallpapers"** in **Laravel version 5.8** and I'm using XAMPP and database is in MySQL and I'm using Visual Studio Code Editor

I've created separate models 'Categories' for table 'categories' and "Images" for table 'images'.

The Problem is that, that mysql query gives me the output I wanted but whenever I try that query in Laravel it generates Syntax Error or Access Violation.

Here is the laravel query that I tried but I am getting the same Syntax Error or Access Violation error

```
1)  $categoryData=DB::select("SELECT categories.cid, categories.category_name, count(images.category) from 'categories' left join 'images' on categories.cid=images.category GROUP BY categories.category_name order by categories.category_name ASC");


2)  $categoryData=DB::table('categories')->leftjoin('images','categories.cid','=','images.category')->select('categories.cid','categories.category_name', DB::raw("COUNT(images.category) as count"))->groupby('categories.category_name')->get();


3)  $categoryData=Categories::leftjoin('images','categories.cid','=','images.category')->select('categories.cid','categories.category_name', DB::raw("count(images.category) as count"))->groupby('categories.category_name')->get();
```

I tried searching on many websites but because I'm new to laravel I couldn't understand what should I do, so please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just group by all the columns you have selected ...

2)

```
$categoryData=DB::table('categories')->leftjoin('images','categories.cid','=','images.category')->select('categories.cid','categories.category_name',DB::raw("COUNT(images.category) as count"))->
```

*`groupby('categories.cid','categories.category_name')->get();`*

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend it for scalable projects, but you can disable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode (which is a constrain for MySQL to execute only queries which contain non ambiguous `GROUP BY` statements) from database configuration.

Go to `/app/database.php` at connections -> mysql, and append the following code to the end:

```
'mysql' => [
   'driver' => 'mysql',
   ....

   // append the following:
   'modes' => [
       //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
       'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
       'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
       'NO_ZERO_DATE',
       'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
       'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
       'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
   ]
]
```

Then execute `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

In `config\database.php` --> "mysql" array

Set

`'strict' => false`

Details is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error)