# Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'adminlte3.orders.name' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: laravel

```
DB::table('orders')
            ->select('orders.id','orders.name', 'orders.phone_number', 'orders.payment_type', 'orders.payment_status', 'orders.payment_status','orders.discount','orders.grand_total','orders.viewed','orders.code','orders.created_at', 'orders.shipping_address','orders.delivery_charge', DB::raw('SUM(order_details.unit_price) As unit_price'))
            ->groupBy('orders.id')
            ->leftJoin('order_details', 'order_details.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')  
            ->paginate($request->per_page);
```

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error

Answer (score 0):

In `config\database.php`, "mysql" array

Set `'strict' => false`

Comment: A lot of thanks...., Its working

Comment: But return 1 row, have multiple row