# Laravel 8.x: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation while running a query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have the  following query which is working fine if executed directly from a phpmyadmin interface

```
SELECT cat.category_id, catName.`name` AS catName, cat.* 
FROM corehub_online_product p 
LEFT JOIN corehub_online_product_to_category cat 
ON cat.product_id = p.product_id 
LEFT JOIN corehub_online_category grp 
ON cat.category_id = grp.category_id 
LEFT JOIN corehub_online_category_description catName 
ON catName.category_id = grp.category_id 
LEFT JOIN corehub_online_category_description grpName 
ON grpName.category_id = grp.parent_id 
WHERE grp.parent_id = 49 AND cat.category_id != '42' 
GROUP BY catName
```

The above sql is generated inside the php code (Laravel framework 8.x) and the statements for the same are given below

```
$dbPrefix = "corehub";
        
         $categoryQP = "
    SELECT cat.category_id, catName.`name` AS catName, cat.*
    FROM ".$dbPrefix."_online_product p
    LEFT JOIN ".$dbPrefix."_online_product_to_category cat ON cat.product_id = p.product_id
    LEFT JOIN ".$dbPrefix."_online_category grp ON cat.category_id = grp.category_id
    LEFT JOIN ".$dbPrefix."_online_category_description catName ON catName.category_id = grp.category_id
    LEFT JOIN ".$dbPrefix."_online_category_description grpName ON grpName.category_id = grp.parent_id
    WHERE grp.parent_id = 49 AND cat.category_id != '42'
    GROUP BY catName";
        
        
        $categories = DB::select($categoryQP);
```

When the above code is executed it throws the following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY
> clause and contains nonaggregated column
> 'yogamaui_testportal.cat.category_id' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: SELECT cat.category_id,
> catName.`name` AS catName, cat.* FROM corehub_online_product p LEFT
> JOIN corehub_online_product_to_category cat ON cat.product_id =
> p.product_id LEFT JOIN corehub_online_category grp ON cat.category_id
> = grp.category_id LEFT JOIN corehub_online_category_description catName ON catName.category_id = grp.category_id LEFT JOIN
> corehub_online_category_description grpName ON grpName.category_id =
> grp.parent_id WHERE grp.parent_id = 49 AND cat.category_id != '42'
> GROUP BY catName)

Can anyone please advice on what might be the problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44984930/6212294) answer your question?

Comment: Having a table name and an alias with the same name is likely to get very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really Laravel preferred way,

But disabling the `strict` mode in `database.php` should make it work

```
// config/database.php

    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            ...
            'strict' => false, // <---
            ...
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: doesn't work with me, commenting the mode make it work in my case (laravel 9x)  

`
'modes' => [
  'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
  'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
  'NO_ZERO_DATE',
  'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
  // 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
  'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
]
`