# Eloquent model cannot select from MySQL view

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-view

Has MySQL view 'histstat'.

In MySQL `select * from histstat` works fine.

Laravel model is very simple:

```
class HistStat extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'histstat';

    protected $fillable = ['day', 'total', 'paid'];
}
```

Then I want to get first 14 records of hisstat:

```
$dynamic = HistStat::all()->slice(14);
```

... and execution ends with error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 (SQL: select * from 'histstat')`

When I try to use table-based model (`$dynamic = History::all()->slice(14);`) - everything works fine.

So, the problem in MySQL view + Laravel.

How to use view-based model in Laravel ?

Comment: why you didn't use limit but using slice instead?

Comment: sorry don't get your problem. but you can't use laravel eloquent query in sql view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Again, if you have a solution, post an answer. DO NOT edit it into your post. The question is for the question, _not_ answers

Answer (score 0):

For the SQL error,

In `config\database.php` in `"mysql"` array

Set `'strict' => false`

I think this one will help [Laravel: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error).

For the first 14 records, you can do it

```
HistStat::oldest()->take(14)->get();
```

better than `all()` because I do not recommend using it if you have a huge table that will be load on the server because `all()` get all records `select * from "users"`

Comment: Sorry, `'strict' => false` do nothing. Error appeared again

Comment: clear cache please and try again.

Comment: Still no effect

Comment: `'strict' => false` is not enough to work safe with MySQL view. See update

Answer (score 0):

In `config/datatable.php` (mysql section):

1. Change `strict` to `false`
2. Add / change in `options` - `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true`