# Laravel Eloquent: How to form "2 Select database" to peform count?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I will ask you.
in sql i have a code like this ?

```php
    SELECT keterangan_warga, COUNT(keterangan_warga) as cnt 
    FROM ( SELECT distinct nokk_warga, keterangan_warga FROM `warga` ) as t
    GROUP by keterangan_warga;
```

then , i will perform this to Laravels. How can I do? Thanks, I try to 2 select but it error.

i will perform this data t laravels like this
[image]
and I try to implement in laravels there is error intelephense in the second **select** and second **from**

```php
$data = DB::selectRaw('keterangan_warga , count(keterangan_warga ) as JumlahWarga')
    ->from( select('nokk_warga', 'keterangan_warga')->distinct()->from('warga'))
    ->groupby('keterangan_warga')
    ->get();
```

The table name is warga, and this is the table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6E6e.png)

I will count keterangan_warga based on nokk_warga, i already successfully show the data that I need in sql but I dont know how to perform it in laravales.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What is the error? What you try in laravel

Comment: Sorry, can you explain more?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin the question is update, do you have any idea to perform this?

Comment: @A.ANoman error intelephense

Comment: Step by step, What is the name of the table? As I know you should add `table('table_name')`.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin oh sory, I have an table name warga, this table contain: 
id (primary key)
no_kk ,
nama_warga, and keterangan_warga. 

But I will count the keterangan_warga based on no_kk, no_kk is a group of some id , in sql i have a code like that and i already show the database like I need, but i will perform it to laravels, but i dont how to perform.

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin I've updated the question and add the 'warga' table into this question, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: heelo @MohamedGamalEldin this is the error Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\select() ,

Comment: Edit DB to this `$data = DB::table('warga')->selectRaw('keterangan_warga , count(keterangan_warga ) as JumlahWarga')->select('nokk_warga', 'keterangan_warga')->groupby('keterangan_warga')->get();` and tell me if the error changed.

Comment: the error changed into this SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'public.warga.nokk_warga' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `nokk_warga`, `keterangan_warga` from `warga` group by `keterangan_warga`)

Comment: try to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error) to fix the error.

Comment: Hello @MohamedGamalEldin after I fix the error , then the error now, the alias table from count not detected, how to fix it? Undefined property: stdClass::$JumlahWarga (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\data_bantuan\resources\views\home.blade.php)