# Laravel GROUP BY without disabling strict mode

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was trying to run this query in laravel:

```
$siswa = DB::table('siswa')
                ->join('pengambilankelas', 'siswa.id_siswa', '=', 'pengambilankelas.id_siswa')
                ->join('subcpmkpengambilan', 'pengambilankelas.id_pengambilanKelas', '=', 'subcpmkpengambilan.id_pengambilanKelas')
                ->join('tesformatif', 'subcpmkpengambilan.id_subcpmkpengambilan', '=', 'tesformatif.id_subcpmkpengambilan')
                ->select('siswa.*', 'tesformatif.*', DB::raw('max(tesformatif.nilai_tesFormatif) as max_nilai'))
                ->groupBy('siswa.id_siswa')
                ->where('pengambilankelas.id_kelas','=', $id_kelas)
                ->where('subcpmkpengambilan.id_subCPMK', '=',  $currentSubcpmk->id_subCpmk)
                ->where('subcpmkpengambilan.status_subcpmkpengambilan', '=',  3)
                ->get();
```

then i got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'dil.siswa.identitas_siswa' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `siswa`.*, `tesformatif`.*, max(tesformatif.nilai_tesFormatif) as max_nilai from `siswa` inner join `pengambilankelas` on `siswa`.`id_siswa` = `pengambilankelas`.`id_siswa` inner join `subcpmkpengambilan` on `pengambilankelas`.`id_pengambilanKelas` = `subcpmkpengambilan`.`id_pengambilanKelas` inner join `tesformatif` on `subcpmkpengambilan`.`id_subcpmkpengambilan` = `tesformatif`.`id_subcpmkpengambilan` where `pengambilankelas`.`id_kelas` = 5 and `subcpmkpengambilan`.`id_subCPMK` = 6 and `subcpmkpengambilan`.`status_subcpmkpengambilan` = 3 group by `siswa`.`id_siswa`)
```

Query run fine outside laravel. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error) tell me to disable strict mode
and it works.

is there a better way without disabling strict mode? is it even save to do so?

ps. I'm sorry the database is in indonesian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have the sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled. To disable it run in the mysql console the following command:

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

**References**
[Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)