# groupBy in Controller Index function

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-blade

I have data that I'm trying to groupBy a field on index function

```
public function index()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('workstep_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');
        $thisUser = Auth::user();
        $worksteps = Workstep::with(['site_id'])->where('site_id', $thisUser->site_id)->get();
        return view('admin.worksteps.process', compact('worksteps'));
    }
```

Adding `->groupBy('subprocess_id');` before`->get();`
As below

```
$worksteps = Workstep::with(['site_id'])->where('site_id', $thisUser->site_id)->groupBy('subprocess_id')->get();
```

produces error

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'tool_db.worksteps.id' isn't in GROUP BY
```

Also tried

```
$grouped = $worksteps->groupBy('subprocess_id');
return view('admin.worksteps.process', compact('worksteps', 'grouped'));
```

Didn't work! Can anyone suggest a solution but **without** a `DB query` if possible?

Comment: Add a ->select('id', 'column1',...) with column names, which you want to get and you want do the sorting.

Comment: r u using mysql connection?

Comment: I just need to groupBy one column, trying to achieve it without db queries

Comment: Connection: mysql yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error)

Answer (score 0):

`without a DB query` chain `->groupBy('subprocess_id')` after `->get()`

```php
$worksteps = Workstep::with(['site_id'])->where('site_id', $thisUser->site_id)->get()->groupBy('subprocess_id');
```

Comment: Tried that before it gives error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: @JessicaKimble can you show: `Workstep::with(['site_id'])->where('site_id', $thisUser->site_id)->get()->dd();`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in database config file `config/database.php`

In mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode
only then

```
$worksteps = Workstep::with(['site_id'])->where('site_id', $thisUser->site_id)->groupBy('subprocess_id')->get();
```

Worked.