# unable to GROUP_CONCAT for 'one to many relationship' when query has multiple other joins

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-eloquentmany

I am unable to use GROUP_CONCAT for 'one to many relationship' when the query has  multiple other joins.

This is the error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2
> of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column 'laravel.profile.id' which is not functionally dependent on
> columns in GROUP BY clause; this is

**The query:**

```
return DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.id','profile.*',DB::raw("group_concat(photos.url_link) as user_images"))
            ->leftjoin('user_photos as photos', 'u.id', '=', 'photos.id')
            ->leftjoin('user_profiles as profile', 'u.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
            /*/* ->groupBy('photos.user_id')*/
            ->groupBy('u.id','profile.user_id')
            ->where('u.id', $id)
            ->first();
```

**Table relationships:**

User is in **'one to many'** relationship with photos

User is in **'one to one'** relationship with profile

the query works if i take out the groupBy and the  'group_concat' part of the query:

```
return DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.id as user_id','profile.*')
            ->leftjoin('user_photos as photos', 'u.id', '=', 'photos.id')
            ->leftjoin('user_profiles as profile', 'u.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
            ->where('u.id', $id)
            ->first();
```

The query also works if I only have one join:

**this query works:**

```
return DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.id',DB::raw("group_concat(photos.url_link) as user_images"))
            ->leftjoin('user_photos as photos', 'u.id', '=', 'photos.id')
            ->groupBy('u.id')
            ->where('u.id', $id)
            ->first();
```

Comment: [Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sELECT+list+is+not+in+GROUP+BY+clause+and+contains+nonaggregate)  error is quite common in SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel : Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917189/laravel-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1055-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the select columns where you're selecting `profile.*`

`profile.*` is adding other columns to the select that aren't in your grouped columns or aggregated like your `GROUP_CONCAT`

If you only select the `profile.user_id` column from the joined profile table your query should work.

```
return DB::table('users as u')
            ->select('u.id','profile.user_id',DB::raw("group_concat(photos.url_link) as user_images"))
            ->leftjoin('user_photos as photos', 'u.id', '=', 'photos.id')
            ->leftjoin('user_profiles as profile', 'u.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')
            /*/* ->groupBy('photos.user_id')*/
            ->groupBy('u.id','profile.user_id')
            ->where('u.id', $id)
            ->first();
```

It may help to think of `GROUP BY` more as an aggregation than actually grouping.

With Laravel's collections, for example, the group method takes records that share the value you're grouping by and organises the collection into a series of sub-collections. It only cares about the data it's grouping by.

With SQL it's more a case of merging a number of records into a single row, it needs to know what to do with the ungrouped values. Let's say you have a table of addresses:

| city | street | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| London | Oxford Street | 100 |
| London | Oxford Street | 101 |
| London | Carnaby Street | 200 |
| London | Carnaby Street | 201 |
| Bristol | Corn Street | 302 |

If I group by City, SQL wants to give me back two records (London and Bristol) so I need to either aggregate the remaining columns with something like `GROUP_CONCAT()` or `MAX()` or further divide the results by adding them to the group parameters.

If I group by City **and** Street then it wants to give me 3 records (London/Oxford Street, London/Carnaby Street and Bristol/Corn Street) so I only need to aggregate the number column.