# SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT in my sql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAllEventIdList_SP`(in skillId varchar(50),in offsetvalue int,in recordlimit int,out totalcountquery text)
BEGIN

 set @whereClause="   ";

 SET @skills=concat('"',skillId,'"');

 if(skillId is not null and skillId <>"" and skillId <>0) then
 set @whereClause=concat(@whereClause," where skill_id in (",@skills ,")");

 end if;
     set totalcountquery=concat("select count(distinct (eventId)) from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause);

  if(offsetvalue<recordlimit) then  
     set @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc ", " limit " ,recordlimit , " offset 0");
     PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

  else 

     set @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc  ",  " limit " ,recordlimit , " offset ", offsetvalue);

     PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

 end if;


END
```

this is my Dynamic Query when i call data  call tju.GetAllEventIdList_SP('1',17, 16, @totalcountquery);
 then i am getting Error 
Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'EventAttachmentList_View.scheduleDate' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

please suggest me how to fix this issue what change required in Query

Comment: In which MySQL version do you get this error?

Answer (score 4):

Your version of MySQL has the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode enabled which means that *(in MySQL 5.7.5 and up)* any query using `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` will require the column(s) in `ORDER BY` to also be in the `SELECT` part of the query.

The fix would be to add `scheduleDate` to the `SELECT` parts of your queries like so:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAllEventIdList_SP`(in skillId varchar(50),in offsetvalue int,in recordlimit int,out totalcountquery text)
BEGIN

 set @whereClause="   ";

 SET @skills=concat('"',skillId,'"');

 if(skillId is not null and skillId <>"" and skillId <>0) then
 set @whereClause=concat(@whereClause," where skill_id in (",@skills ,")");

 end if;
     set totalcountquery=concat("select count(distinct (eventId)) from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause);

  if(offsetvalue<recordlimit) then
     set @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId,scheduleDate from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc ", " limit " ,recordlimit , " offset 0");
     PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

  else

     set @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId,scheduleDate from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc  ",  " limit " ,recordlimit , " offset ", offsetvalue);

     PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

 end if;


END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAllEventIdList_SP`(in skillId varchar(50),in offsetvalue int,in recordlimit int,out totalcountquery text)
BEGIN

 set @whereClause="   ";

 SET @skills=concat('"',skillId,'"');

 if(skillId is not null and skillId <>"" and skillId <>0) then
 set @whereClause=concat(@whereClause," where skill_id in (",@skills ,")");

 end if;
     set totalcountquery=concat("select count(distinct (eventId)) from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause);

  if(offsetvalue<recordlimit) then  
     set @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc ", " limit " ,recordlimit , " offset 0");
     PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

  else 

     set @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc  ",  " limit " ,recordlimit , " offset ", offsetvalue);

     PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
     EXECUTE querystatement;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;

 end if;


END;

CALL GetAllEventIdList_SP('1',17, 16, @totalcountquery);
```

I had tried.It's working fine.[image]

Comment: But in my m machine and mysql verison i am getting . SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT in my sql @Sagar Gangwal

Answer (score 0):

Add comma between LIMIT and OFFSET parameters. The query should be like this:

```
...LIMIT 16, OFFSET 17
```

Also, optimize your code, try to use this code instead of `if(offsetvalue<recordlimit)...` -

```
SET @offset = IF(offsetvalue < recordlimit, 0, offsetvalue);
SET @SqlQuery=concat("select distinct (eventId),scheduleId from EventAttachmentList_View ",@whereClause,  " order by scheduleDate desc  ",  " limit " ,recordlimit , ", offset ", @offset);
PREPARE querystatement FROM @SqlQuery;
EXECUTE querystatement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE querystatement;
```

Comment: , is not fixing my issue still i am getting  @Devart

Comment: Try to check generated sql query. For example, add `SELECT @SqlQuery;` instead of prepared statement execution.

Comment: You also can debug this procedure and view all its parameters with Debug tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (trial version).

Comment: @Devrat in other Sql version given Query is working but in  my machine mysql version its not working Error Code: 3065. Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'EventAttachmentList_View.scheduleDate' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
 can u please tell me SOlution

Comment: Can you show generated statement? (to understand the situation)