# typo3 setup of tt_products from scratch but no products are shown

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I am trying to setup tt_products from scratch on T3 11.5.

- tt_products included in template
- sysfolder with one product and some categries
- page with plugin Products:List - but no product is shown!
- page with plugin Categories:menu - categories are shown!

No typoscript changes, no own typoscript, all settings via BE form of tt_products.

What do I miss to see the dummy product?

Help appreciated!

Regards
Karl-Heinz

Comment: have you selected your data folder in TypoScript or plugin as a source?

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ,
yes, I did! I can see, that the template is not imported in the website HTML. For "Category:menu" I get an error message if the template is not available (file not found). "Products:List" does not bring this error message.

Comment: verify that the typoscript is included - and not overwritten. especially the `...Paths` arrays with the paths to the templates are correct. check with TypoScriptObjectBrwoser (TSOB) and analyzer.

Comment: according to TSOB: ```[templateFile] = EXT:tt_products/template/example_locallang_xml.html```. If I delete the file (or rename) I get an error at "Category:menu": ```Shop Plugin: The subpart part marker ###ITEM_CATEGORY_MENU_TEMPLATE### or the template file has not been found.``` Similar on "Products:search", but nothing on "Products:list".

Comment: you may get more information if you debug the data. Is there data at all?  as this output is temporary you might modify the templates of the extension and insert `<f:debug title="identify debug line">{_all}</f:debug>` in different files. Otherwise make a copy and add the new paths to the `...paths` arrays.

Comment: `subpart part marker`???? no FLUID but marker templates? Either this message needs an update or something is very wrong.

Comment: as far as I see the setup of tt_products 2.14 it is not (!!not!!) fluid based. Yes, it has the file structure, but the templates are still MARKER based - like the "old style templates of T3". Probably I missunderstand something - but!?

Comment: how can I get more information on ```Oops, an error occurred! Code: 2023020613220780136680```?

Comment: you're leaving the context of your question. you can get more information (call stack) if you switch that instance to debug mode where more information is given. `Configuration Presets` -> `Debug settings` -> `(x) Debug`

Answer (score 0):

both situations occured! Once with simply no data, once with the "Oops...", depending how I configured the content element for the plugin.

Through some more investigation on the logfile I found some more details and finally came to that solution, with some help of the tt_products owner:

Result:
mysql setting: "sql_mode"

Described here:
[How to resolve "ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list" caused MySQL 5.7 with SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829911/how-to-resolve-order-by-clause-is-not-in-select-list-caused-mysql-5-7-with-sel)